# Xamarin.Forms UWP project wont install on windows 10 mobile

Tags: windows-10-mobile

I am not able to install the appbundle file in windows phone 10

I have tried copying the file on device and also via the winappdeploycmd.exe tool

But nothing works!

Comment: Has anyone been successful in what I am doing?

Comment: After doing some research it looks like Xamarin-forms-samples apps cannot be deployed on windows 10 (10.14393 version). I have to wait for an upgrade for my mobile

Answer (score 0):

If you use [.Net Standard 2.0 and Xamarin.Forms 3.0 you can't install the app on Windows 10 Mobile](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2018/02/14/why-cant-i-deploy-my-uwp-app-with-net-standard-2-0-to-a-mobile-device-or-emulator/), because .Net Standard 2.0 support was added with the Windows 10 v1709 Build 16299, but Microsoft never released that version for phones. They hang at lower [feature2 branch with Build 15254](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_Mobile#Fall_Creators_update).

So you have 2 options:

- use PCL as shared code with [Xamarin.Forms 2.5.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/2.5.1.527436) and Min/TargetBuild 14393/15063 to serve both, Desktop/Tablets and phones
- create separate brach/app with PCL for mobile (Min/TargetBuild 14393/15063) and 1 app for desktop which uses .net standard 2.0 (Min/TargetBuild 16299/16299) and latest Xamarin.Forms version.

Comment: What do I need to do to make it work on my mobile. I am following what you told me and changing the versions causes the uwp app to unavailable

Comment: Do you want to serve both in 1 app or have 2 apps? See my 2 options at the end

Comment: I just want the app to run on my mobile 14393 version

Comment: ok, do first option. use [PCL library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/cross-platform/cross-platform-development-with-the-portable-class-library#create_pcl) where you put all your Views and logic and only install  Xamarin.Forms  2.5.1 and never update Xamarin.Forms to version 3.

Comment: I have the 3.0 version by default. I can change it via the pm command. But isn't there a simple solution like changing the version? I have a Xamarin-forms-samples todo app which has 16299 version. How should I use the sample app to deploy on my 14393 mobile version

Comment: in Manage NuGet Packages UI, change the version back to the highest 2.5 version and for the UWP app, open the properties and set the MinVersion to 14393

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171339/discussion-between-sly-chandan-and-magicandre1981).