# Xamarin crashing between two errors

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I try to create a new Xamarin.Forms project for Android and Windows Phone, but I'm getting stucked by two errors.

First of all, I have the following error:

```
DEP3321: To deploy this application, your deployment target should be running Windows Universal Runtime version 10.0.16299.0 or higher. You currently are running version 10.0.14393.0. Please update your OS, or change your deployment target to a device with the appropriate version.
```

I've found the solution for this error, on some forums people said that setting the TargetMinVersionPlatform to the current running version of Windows Universal Runtime and setting the TargetVersionPlatform to the expected one should resolve the error. Yes it's true, but now I'm receiving another error:

```
NU1201 Project App3 is not compatible with uap10.0.14393 (UAP,Version=v10.0.14393) / win10-x86. Project App3 supports: netstandard1.6 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.6)
```

and after I did some research I found that this problem is resolved by doing backwards all the workarounds that I've did for resolving the first problem.

So, in conclusion I'm being stucked between this two errors. Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: [I posted it yesterday in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50394455/1466046). You can't use Xamarin.Forms 3 and .net standard 2.0 when you build UWP apps for phones. you can only use them on PC/Tablet WIndows 10 with at least Build 16299

Answer (score 1):

As the [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) document, netstandard 2.0 can be used on UWP version 10.0.16299. It can not be used on UWP version 14393, so you can not change your app target min version to 14393. Currently, Windows phone version is 15254 and you can not run the .net standard 2.0 on windows phone. So the solution would be like @ magicandre1981 said on his thread [Xamarin.Forms UWP project wont install on windows 10 mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379799/xamarin-forms-uwp-project-wont-install-on-windows-10-mobile/50394455#50394455)

Besides, you can also try to create your Xamarin app target version 14393 on the VS 2015 directly.